# 74LS14 datasheet question (Short-circuit output current)

Tags: current, short-circuit, 7400

the 6th row in the table (Short-circuit output current).

When exactly this value is to be considered? (When output shorted to ground? or Vcc?)
And does it mean I have to consider this value (i.e using external resistor) or is it just what's built into the chip?

[image: the row with Ios symbol]

Comment: If you look at the rest of the operating conditions, you should see that we refer to high level output current (output in the high state) as a negative value. That means that the \$I_{OS}\$ value is for the output in the high state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JEDEC defines short-circuit output current as:

> short-circuit output current (IOS)
>
> (1) (of a digital integrated circuit)
>
> The current into an output terminal when the output is short-circuited to ground with input conditions applied that, according to the product specification, will establish the output logic furthest from ground potential.
>
> (2) (of an analog integrated circuit):
>
> The output current with the output shorted to ground or other specified point.
>
> References:
> JESD99B, 5/07 JESD99B, 5/07

Source: https://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/dictionary/terms/short-circuit-output-current-ios-1-digital-integrated-circuit

You might be interested in I_OS if, for instance, you are driving a relative large capacitive load. Such a load would initially appear as a short to ground when the capacitor is fully discharged.

The TI publication ["Designing With Logic"](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sdya009c/sdya009c.pdf) contains a wealth of tips and information that is very helpful when designing with digital logic. Section 6.3 talks about how I_OS is related to the propagation delay time into a capacitive load and the device's output impedance.